# Django App requires www in URL

Tags: python, django, apache, .htaccess, mod-wsgi

I just recently launched my Django app on an apache server using mod_wsgi.  If I don't put www in the URL, I always get a 404 error.  I.e. "example.com" redirects to "http://www.example.com/wsgi.py" with a 404 error.

While the following URL works fine:

www.example.com/about

if I just type "example.com/about" I get redirected to a 404 page at www.example.com/wsgi.py/about.

Any idea why this is happening?  My allowed hosts has "*" in it.  I also tried ".example.com" instead.

Additionally I have an .htaccess file in my site www root with the following rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#using-mod-wsgi-daemon-mode

Comment: @dylrei Can you point me to a specific part of that?  Of course I have read it, this is how I launched my application.  I guess I probably messed something up, but I have no idea what hence my question on here.

Comment: It's not clear where you diverged from the documented approach. The code that's copied in doesn't really relate to it at all, so I assume there's more. The suggestion about using vhosts should also address your challenge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a better solution to use a virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias example.com
    RedirectMatch permanent ^/(.*) http://www.example.com/$1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ...your config here...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: my hosting company doesn't let me edit my httpd.conf files